# convert android.graphics.Bitmap to java.io.File

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I want to upload edited Bitmap image to server using multipart uploading like this,

```
multipartEntity.addPart("ProfilePic", new FileBody(file));
```

But I can't convert **Bitmap**(`android.graphics.Bitmap`) image to **File**(`java.io.File`).

I tried to convert it to byte array but It also didn't worked.

Does anybody know inbuilt function of android or any solution to convert Bitmap to File?

Please help...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769806/convert-bitmap-to-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274715/save-bitmap-to-file-function

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This should do it:

```
private static void persistImage(Bitmap bitmap, String name) {
  File filesDir = getAppContext().getFilesDir();
  File imageFile = new File(filesDir, name + ".jpg");

  OutputStream os;
  try {
    os = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error writing bitmap", e);
  }
}
```

Change the `Bitmap.CompressFormat` and extension to suit your purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I needed to upload the image captured as an application/octet-stream using Retrofit and your code worked. +1

Answer (score 1):

Although the selected answer is correct but for those who are looking for Kotlin code. Here I have already written a detailed article on the topic for both Java and Kotlin. [Convert Bitmap to File in Android](https://handyopinion.com/convert-bitmap-to-file-in-android-java-kotlin/).

```
fun bitmapToFile(bitmap: Bitmap, fileNameToSave: String): File? { // File name like "image.png"
        //create a file to write bitmap data
        var file: File? = null
        return try {
            file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + fileNameToSave)
            file.createNewFile()

            //Convert bitmap to byte array
            val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos) // YOU can also save it in JPEG
            val bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray()

            //write the bytes in file
            val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
            fos.write(bitmapdata)
            fos.flush()
            fos.close()
            file
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            file // it will return null
        }
    }
```