# Open Image and make it a File in Android and send it in a Json

Tags: android, json, file, imageview, android-volley

Ok so what I am trying to do is to open an image, set it in an imageview and make it a file in order to send it in a multipartform request using volley, right now I am using PostMan to make Http Requests to my server (string and file) and it is working properly but I can not implement it in android what I have so far is this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == banner){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        //Verified the android version
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19){

            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        } else{
            //KitKat 4.4 o superior
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        }
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, request_code);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == request_code) {
        uri = data.getData();
        banner.setImageURI(uri);
        //TAG for store the Uri to the selected file
        banner.setTag(uri);
        path = uri.getPath();
        fileImage = new File (path);
        Toast.makeText(this,path,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

Where banner is my imageview and fileImage is my file

```
MultipartRequest myRequest = new MultipartRequest(
            "MY_URL",
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.e("error");
                }
            },
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    VolleyLog.e(response);
                }
            },
            fileImage,
            params
    );
```

I am using this class that was answered in another question

```
public class MultipartRequest extends Request<String> {

//private MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
HttpEntity httpentity;
private static final String FILE_PART_NAME = "banner";

private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
private final File mFilePart;
private final Map<String, String> mStringPart;

public MultipartRequest(String url, Response.ErrorListener errorListener,
                        Response.Listener<String> listener,
                        File file,
                        Map<String, String> mStringPart) {
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

    mListener = listener;
    mFilePart = file;
    this.mStringPart = mStringPart;
    entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    buildMultipartEntity();
}

public void addStringBody(String param, String value) {
    mStringPart.put(param, value);
}

private void buildMultipartEntity() {
    entity.addPart(FILE_PART_NAME, new FileBody(mFilePart));
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mStringPart.entrySet()) {
        entity.addTextBody(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return httpentity.getContentType().getValue();
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        httpentity = entity.build();
        httpentity.writeTo(bos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}

@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    return Response.success("Uploaded", getCacheEntry());
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}
```

}

But it return me the error "IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send a “multipart/form-data” POST in Android with Volley](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797468/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-post-in-android-with-volley)

Comment: I am using that class but My question is how to make it a FILE once I open the image

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just saving the image to file, take a look at this post, you need to turn the image received as a bitmap first and then just follow what's written in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274715/save-bitmap-to-file-function) post

Comment: Actually I don't know exactly what I am trying to do, all I know is that I need to open an image and make it a File to send it in a MultipartFormRequest

Comment: And no I don't want to store the image in my device